# Caused by: com.alibaba.otter.canal.common.CanalException: requestGet for canal config error: auth :admin is failed

Tags: kubernetes

I am now using Alibaba [Canal](https://github.com/alibaba/canal) to sync MySQL from datacenter A to datacenter B(the canal deploy in kubernetes), after I start the canal-server, shows error like this:

```
[root@canal-server-stable-0 bin]# tail -f /home/canal/logs/canal/canal.log 
2021-05-26 11:47:32.329 [main] INFO  com.alibaba.otter.canal.deployer.CanalLauncher - ## set default uncaught exception handler
2021-05-26 11:47:32.366 [main] INFO  com.alibaba.otter.canal.deployer.CanalLauncher - ## load canal configurations
2021-05-26 11:47:32.849 [main] ERROR com.alibaba.otter.canal.deployer.CanalLauncher - ## Something goes wrong when starting up the canal Server:
com.alibaba.otter.canal.common.CanalException: load manager config failed.
Caused by: com.alibaba.otter.canal.common.CanalException: requestGet for canal config error: auth :admin is failed
2021-05-26 11:52:50.402 [main] INFO  com.alibaba.otter.canal.deployer.CanalLauncher - ## set default uncaught exception handler
2021-05-26 11:52:50.432 [main] INFO  com.alibaba.otter.canal.deployer.CanalLauncher - ## load canal configurations
2021-05-26 11:52:50.836 [main] ERROR com.alibaba.otter.canal.deployer.CanalLauncher - ## Something goes wrong when starting up the canal Server:
com.alibaba.otter.canal.common.CanalException: load manager config failed.
Caused by: com.alibaba.otter.canal.common.CanalException: requestGet for canal config error: auth :admin is failed
```

this is my canal server config:

```
[root@canal-server-stable-0 bin]# cat ../conf/canal.properties 
# register ip
# canal.register.ip =   canal-server-stable-0.canal-server-discovery-svc-stable.hades-pro.svc.cluster.local
canal.register.ip = 10.244.5.5

# canal admin config
canal.admin.manager = 10.105.49.36:8089
canal.admin.port = 11110
canal.admin.user = admin
canal.admin.passwd = 6bb4837eb74329105ee4568dda7dc67ed2ca2ad9
# admin auto register
canal.admin.register.auto = true
canal.admin.register.cluster = online
```

the hash password was encrypt from `123456`. I am sure the password is right. I tried to find the password in database, it matched with my config:

[image]

I also using Arthas to trace the online app of canal-admin:

```
watch com.alibaba.otter.canal.admin.controller.PollingConfigController auth "{params,returnObj}" -x 3 -b
```

shows the password I pass is: `6bb4837eb74329105ee4568dda7dc67ed2ca2ad9`. I did not know where is going wrong now, what should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

you can check canal admin conf/application.yaml file

```
canal:
 adminUser: admin
 adminPasswd: 123456
```

if you modified "canal.adminPasswd" attribute, you can modified it correct.

hope, help you.